# combo DrRacket implicit else

Tags: lisp, racket

Why does this work?

```
(define (rev l)
  (cond ((null? l) l)
        (else (append (rev(cdr l)) (list (car l))))))
```

Output:

```
> (rev L1)
(d c b a)
```

and this not?

```
(define (rev l)
  (cond ((null? l) l)
    (append (rev(cdr l)) (list (car l)))))
```

Output:

```
> (rev L1)
(a)
```

Isn't "else" implicit in Lisp?

Answer (score 3):

In the second example the procedure `append` is the predicate and since it is a procedure and every value except `#f` is true it does the consequent `(rev (cdr l))`

`cond` has to have its terms in parentheses. There is no explicit `else`, thought if neither predicate matches the implementation can choose the result (undefined value).

`if` is a different conditional that perhaps is better suited in this case.

```
(define (rev l)
  (if (null? l)
      l
      (append (rev (cdr l))
              (list (car l)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the indentation makes it easier to see what happens:

```
(define (rev l)
  (cond
    [(null? l)  l]
    [else       (append (rev(cdr l)) (list (car l)))]))

(define (rev l)
  (cond
    [(null? l)  l]
    [append     (rev(cdr l))
                (list (car l))]))
```

Note that in the second version you have a clause

```
    [append     (rev(cdr l))
                (list (car l))]))
```

When the `cond`-expression is evaluated it tries to evaluate each left hand side until it finds one that gives a non-false value. Here the left-hand side `append` evaluates to the append function, which is a non-false value.

The next thing that happens, is the right hand side is evaluated. Due to an implicit begin on the right hand side, this is evaluated:

```
              (begin
                (rev(cdr l))
                (list (car l)))
```

To conclude: You accidentally wrote an expression that had correct syntax, but meant something different than you expected.

Note that the error is easier to spot, if you use square brackets around the clauses in the cond. (The square brackets [] and the standard () mean the same).